# API modelling: Two resources with the same name

Tags: api, rest, api-design, modeling

I have an API modelling question I need help with.

Let's assume I have **Product** representation that consists of:

| Attribute | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | string |
| names | MultilingualName List |
| price | decimal |

*MultilingualName* is represented by:

| Attribute | Type |
| --- | --- |
| locale | string |
| name | string |

This is to support multiple languages, so that a store owner user is able to create products (and maintain/CRUD) within a product shelf that supports multiple languages.

Our POST API (/products) may look like this:

```
{
    "id": "123abcxyz"
    "names": [
                {
                    "locale": "en-CA",
                    "name": "Pencil"
                },
                {
                    "locale": "fr-CA",
                    "name": "Crayon"
                }
             ],
    "price": 1.99
                         
}
```

The problem I am having trouble with is with the consumer user based GET end point for **Product**.

I would like to model the resource without having the MultilingualName language complexity. So for example, the GET endpoint would look like this:

| Attribute | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | string |
| name | string |
| price | decimal |

The end point would return the product name based on the user's preferred language, which is already known.

But clearly I have a problem. I have two Products resources now: CRUD operations (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) geared to the store owner that maintains their product shelf (with the language complexity), and one for the consumer user (GET only, without the language complexity).

How should I approach this model? Is this a naming problem or am I approaching the modelling incorrectly?

Thanks for your help.

Edit: adding a UML as suggest by @qwerty_so.
[image: API Model UML diagram]

Comment: Would it be too difficult to supply a class diagram sketch along with your question if you already tagged it with UML?

Comment: @qwerty_so done. Hope it helps!

Comment: The `ProductNames` are an association class and not an attribute of `Product`.

Comment: You don't have a UML but a design issue here. You probably want a `Consumer` to have a different view (e.g. just localized names) on your product rather than a `Store owner` seeing the full ship. There are lots of ways to model that, constraints being one of them.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely a design issue that I need help with. I've clarified the flags to make that clear. This is not a UML question - the diagram was only provided to help understand the design problem.

Comment: @qwerty_so you correct on the intent with having two views. How would constraints work?

Comment: You just attach a free text (or OCL if you dare)  in curly brackets and attach it to say `Product` to tell that `Consumer` will only see the localized description. That would ne enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remark: answer provided when question had an UML tag** (last part still valid though)

### Multiple problems in your diagram:

- An actor is a classifier that is external to the system.  A class can therefore not be associated with an actor.
- A `«use»` dependency should be noted with a dashed line arrow, and not a plain line arrow.
- It is not clear what the links between your `«Representation»` classes and you »`«DB table»` represents:  is it again a dependency?  Is it a navigable association?
- You have multiple definitions of a name without any possibility to disambiguate.

### How to do it in UML?

In UML, having two classes with the same name in the same namespace is not valid, since it would not be clear which class is meant.

Nevertheless, you could adjust your model and separate the different family of classes, enclosing them in distinct [packages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_(UML)), e.g. `Database`, `CRUD`, `Consumer`.

A package defines a namespaces. In consequence all references to a `Product` in the CRUD package would refer to the relevant CRUD class.

For relations between classes of different packages, you may disambiguate with a qualified name (i.e. including the package names), or, in case there would be no conflict, by importing a package into another.

### Is it the best way to design your API?

Managing conflicting names in endpoints is not ideal. It’s n easy source of confusion. You can of course find technical solutions to address this, but still, why bother ?

Why not leave the client side tailoring/simplifying data as needed (e.g. using the user's language by default, unless something else is required)?

Why not let the end-point query parameters provide an optional language code to filter the set of returned languages ?

Or why not just use different names to call differently different things?  I was thinging about `ProductLocalized` or `ProductShort`?

Comment: Hi @Christophe, thank you for your reply but the diagram was only provided quickly to help explain the problem. UML is not the problem I am seeking help with and I have clarified the tags to show this, but this is an api modelling/design problem. Not to say the UML pointers are not appreciated, thanks.

Comment: As for your points on conflicting names, I believe this is what I really need help with. I essentially have two GET endpoints with the same name but serves a GET function in two ways. One provides the store owner/administrator to see all information, and in this case, all supported languages for products. This is important to support CREATE and UPDATE operations as the other localized GET endpoint used by a consumer is incomplete and has been simplified to reduce complexity (ie. you get the product names based on your preferred language).

Comment: I was thinking to do what you suggested with naming (ex. ProductLocalized or ProductShort) given there are two representations! But I was not sure if I was adding complexity unnecessarily.

Comment: @KJY the UML namespace suggestion is very close to the end point naming (e.g. storeOwner/product vs shopper/product). The issue with confusion is still valid in the new context. If you have different representations, distinct name prevent any ambiguity;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a naming problem or am I approaching the modelling incorrectly?

It sounds to me like a naming problem.

It's perfectly reasonable to have more than one resource whose representations are derived from the same underlying data.

But each resource does need to have an identifier of its own.  The machines don't particularly care what the identifier is, so you could use...

```
/b6d5cc6a-e4b3-4bc9-90d0-723f1d8ee22a
/5952d730-d447-4537-9bf0-74cdc2f9f79a
```

But human beings generally copy better with identifiers that are human readable.

Any spelling consistent with your local conventions is *fine*.

One possibility would be to just encode the name of the audience into the identifier itself

```
/storeOwner/products/123
/shopper/products/123
```

or you might instead choose names that are more closely aligned with the business capability

```
/inventory/products/123
/sales/products/123
```

You've got the freedom to choose which human beings you want to optimize for (domain experts? operators reading access logs? tech writers documenting the api? remote developers consuming it? and so on).

Comment: The issue with this approach is that the problem I am facing is "products" would not be the same resource, so it would not work in your examples unless two separate specifications/standards are created - which could get confusing and harder to manage. I believe the ideal approach is listed below by distinguishing the differences through naming of these resources.